# Getting numbered dependency triples in python from stanford dependency parser

Tags: python, dependencies, nlp, stanford-nlp

this question has been making me think for quite some time and i did not find a satisfying solution for it.

Well, right now I am using the Stanford dependency parser in Python and the following code gives me this output.

```
phrase="If there is a moose in the oven, is there also an elephant?"
dependency_parser = StanfordDependencyParser(path_to_jar=path_to_jar, path_to_models_jar=path_to_models_jar)
test = dependency_parser.raw_parse(phrase)
dep= test.next()


list(dep.triples())
```

((u'is', u'VBZ'), u'advcl', (u'is', u'VBZ'))

((u'is', u'VBZ'), u'mark', (u'If', u'IN'))

((u'is', u'VBZ'), u'expl', (u'there', u'EX'))

and so on...

But what i actually need is some representation which includes the number of occcurence within the original sentence, because the final application will consist of long sentences with multiple occurences of the same words. 
Something like:

mark(is-3, If-1)

Thank you in advance for any idea on how to generate such an output!

Answer (score 0):

If you use the Java server and access it with the Python client you can get the token indices in the returned JSON.

Here is info on starting up a Java Stanford CoreNLP server:

https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/corenlp-server.html

I would recommend installing the `stanza` Python module and using the client it has for the Stanford CoreNLP server.

Info for installing and using `stanza` can be found here:

https://github.com/stanfordnlp/stanza

The returned JSON with the dependencies will have the indices of the tokens.